# How to retrieve the databaseName and the serverName from the connectionstring in the webconfig?

Tags: asp.net

How Do I get the connection string from the Web Config?
I want to Display the database and the server name on to my master ASP.net page(C#).

The connection string in my web.config looks:

```
<add name="Application_ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;Connection Timeout =60;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 30):

There's also the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class:

```
var connectionString = 
  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;Connection Timeout =60;Integrated Security=SSPI"); 

Console.WriteLine(connectionString.DataSource);
Console.WriteLine(connectionString.InitialCatalog);
// ...
```

#### Response to comment:

To get the connection strings directly from configuration, use:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings c in System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(c.ConnectionString)
    //connectionString.DataSource; // server name
    //connectionString.InitialCatalog; // database name
}
```

Note that this will include connection strings in your machine.config (e.g. `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true`). If you don't want to see that you can filter it in code or add a `<clear />` element to your web.config before your connection strings.

Comment: I want to retrieve the connection string from the webconfig; I don't want to hardcore the connection string in the code

Comment: I have severals  *connection strings in the webconfig*. Maybe using `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` for each connection string ?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me :

```
        var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconnectionstringname"].ConnectionString;
        var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conn);
        textboxServer.Text = csb.DataSource;
        textboxUserName.Text = csb.UserID;
        textboxPassword.Text = csb.Password;
        textboxInitialCatalog.Text = csb.InitialCatalog;
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

[SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) has a [Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.database.aspx) property so you can get the db name from that after you create the connection.

You can get the *Instance Name* by using the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.datasource.aspx) property on the SqlConnection class.  Instance is similar to the server name but not exactly the same.

Comment: Works for MySql too: 

var mcsb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your_connection_string"].ConnectionString);
var pwd = mcsb.Password;

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework and you're getting an error because your connection string starts with `metadata`, use the following

```
var c = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(new EntityConnectionStringBuilder("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING").ProviderConnectionString);
// c.DataSource; // server name
// c.InitialCatalog; // database name
```